# Git Branches - Ignore File in Merging

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, branching-and-merging

Say I have two branches, `master` and `staging`, and I would like to have two different versions of `/robots.txt` within each branch:

master:

```
# www.robotstxt.org/
# Allow crawling of all content
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

staging

```
# www.robotstxt.org/
# Disallow crawling of all content
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Leaving aside best practices for managing a staging environment, how can I merge in updates from staging to master and vice-versa while ignoring this file?  I've tried a .gitattributes file that says: `robots.txt merge=ours`, but this only occurs when there are merge conflicts and/or is not applicable to this workflow.

Any Ideas?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ ?

Comment: Branching is not the appropriate tool for managing a test-versus-deploy configuration difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a `robots.txt.test` and `robots.txt.deploy`, accompanied by a build process which deploys the appropriate one based on what kind of image you're generating: e.g. an image for internal testing, versus external deployment.

Or, possibly, a single file `robots.txt.in` which contains a preprocessing language that generates `robots.txt` based on some inputs.

Branching is not the appropriate tool for maintaining different types of configuration in the same set of configuration files, for "internal" versus "live" deployment and such.

Merging is used when two divergent streams must combine into one. This cannot work if they have to maintain differences, like different values in the same configuration file. When you merge two branches which have a `robots.txt` in the sample place in the tree, the result must be one `robots.txt`.

If you want to maintain two streams which are diverged indefinitely, then you don't merge. You can use `git cherry-pick` to copy individual changes from one to the other.

You avoid cherry picking any changes which touch the `robots.txt`, or at least those lines in `robots.txt` which are not common.

Adding a file under version control, but then trying to get the version control to ignore it, is blatantly oxymoronic.

Answer (score 1):

several options:

#### .gitignore

Add the file to .gitignore file

```
// .gitignore content
robots.txt
```

---

#### assume-unchanged

use this on the file which you don't want git to track

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

---

#### `git add -p`

Add the desired part per branch (add patch)

[image]